# session is not setting when session name and session id changes

Tags: php, session, cookies

I want to change session name & session id in my admin login panel.
In my admin panel cookies are set to http only

My problem is session is not setting. is there is any problem with my code 
Please help

codes are
index.php

```
<?php
session_name("websitename");//session name changed
if (session_start()) {
    session_regenerate_id(true);//session id changed
    //$sess_name=session_name();
    setcookie("websitename", session_id(), null, '/', null, null, true);//set cookie httponly  
}

$_SESSION['admin']="login";
header("Location: home.php");
?>
```

...........................................................................................

home.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['admin']))
echo "you are logout";
else
echo "you are in home";
?>
```

the site printing 'you are logout'

Comment: The idea of session naming is to separate sessions from each other (mostly when you run two or more projects that use sessions on one machine). so session with the name `name1` does not share any information with session with the name `name2`.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is to insert the line: 
 session_name("websitename");
as the first line of home.php

Why? For those that find themselves here trying to understand the difference between session_name and session_id in PHP, I offer this explanation:

Your session data is in what I will call a "datastore" on the PHP server. Typically it is a disk file, but it could just as well be a database depending on how PHP and the application are implemented on your particular server (PHP allows applications to over ride the session storage provided natively.

Your session data is in the form of a "ragged array".

The ragged array is stored in the datastore using a key that is unique for each session.

To get the session data from the datastore to your php script, you have to have the right key for the desired session.

What happens in index.php in the example code above is:

1. You do a session_name(); Which tells PHP not to use the default session name (PHPSESSID) to access the cookie data, but instead to use website name
2. You do a session_start(); PHP looks for a cookie sent from the browser that has the key "website" name. It does not find one, so it creates a new session by generating a random session id (let us call it "A1"; It stores the new session id in a cookie with the key of "websitename"; It initializes the session data to an empty array.(as if you had done $_SESSION=array();)
3. You have an if statement where you check to see if the session started. The way you use this is odd. If the session did start you redo most of what session start just did for you (all but initialize the array). At ths point let us assume that the new, regenerated session id os "B2". But then you fall through and execute two more statements that do not make any sense if the session did not start. If the session did not start setting the admin key in $_SESSION is pointless as is redirecting to home.php which depends on the session being successfully initialized by index.php.  It makes more sense to me that if session start fails, you log a message to the sysadmin or your self that the site is not configured correctly. If the site is configured for sessions, session start will always return true.
4. You now set a session variable with the key "admin" to the value of "login" by making it an element of the super global array $_SESSION.
5. When you fall through the bottom of index.php (exit it), PHP writes the current contents of the $_SESSION array to the datastore using the key that is in the cookie (ie, "B2" where other scripts can find it. The session data stored to the datastore usng key "B2" is the $_SESSION array with the single element with the key "admin" and value of "login"

When you examine, your code in home.php I believe this is what is happening:

1. You do a session_start(). Because you did not do a prior session_name(), PHP uses the default name of PHPSESSID.  PHP looks for a cookie sent from the browser with a key of you session name (PHPSESSID) and does not find one. So it creates a new session. It generates a new random session id for the session, let's call it "C3"; it initializes the session data ($_SESSION) to an empty array and creates a cookie with a key of PHPSESSID and a value of the random session id that was created for your session ("C3").
2. You do an if/else where you check to see if the session data has an element with a key of 'admin'. The session array is empty so the if else chooses the false branch and prints that the user is not logged in.

Your code is more complicated than this because of the "if" in index.php but to simplify the issue:

You stored your admin value in the session data store using the key "B2" and then looked for it in home.php with the key "C3" and could not find it. This is because you are using the session name of "websitename" in index.php but you are using the session name of "PHPSESSIONID" in home.php.  If you look at the cookies using the resources tab of chrome developer tools, you will see cookies for both "websitename" and "PHPSESSIONID". In developer tools, the cookies will show the real, random, session ids (26 characters) instead of the two character session ids that I made up for this discussion.

Comment: This is one of the best answers I've seen in sof.